# from visual import * not working (vpython)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, vpython

I just downloaded `vPython` for `Python 2.7.9` and got the following error when importing the `.visual` library:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Untitled", line 1
        from visual import *
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\visual\__init__.py", line 3
        from visual.visual_all import * # this statement not included in vis/__init__.py
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\visual\visual_all.py", line 10
        from visual_common.cvisual import vector
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

To avoid confusion I tried reinstalling both `Python` and `vPython` and made sure that it is the 64-bit version.
I don't know if it's an issue with my `python27` files or if I downloaded it wrong. Does anyone know how to solve the error?

Comment: The specifics aside - you should avoid using [import *](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/8881141) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the `Python` installation but with the `Numpy` module.

From the command line type:

> pip install numpy --upgrade

This command will either install the `Numpy` module if you don't have it, or it will upgrade it to the 64-bit version.

If you have never used `pip` then navigate to `C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/pip/`, double click on the `init.py` file and then double click on the `main.py` file. This will install `pip` which you can then use to download any `Python` module from the command line by typing:

> pip install "module name".

Comment: Try to briefly explain what is your approach to consider this as the correct answer and format the pieces of code properly.